# Forge Viewer 7.X : Make vertex visible on mobile

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I need to show the edges of the geometries on mobile using the Forge Viewer 7.X but since version 6.X edges are hidden to improve mobile performance.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v6/

> Vertex array objects default to false on mobile devices to save memory

It's there a way to turn them on again?

PS: The same log shows a render setting **renderEnvironmentDisplayEdges** but I can't find where it should be set.

[Edit] To comply with @Peter O. comment:

It is possible to create an override to a Three.js implementation to show meshes edges after the geometry is already loaded/created?

The solution I found have to be made while loading the geometry but the process is being taken care by the Forge Viewer so I'm not sure if I can apply it.
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/EdgesGeometry

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.  It should be asked on another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @PeterO. The most frustrating thing is that Autodesk has taken an open-source library, built proprietary software with it, and [outsources its support on this proprietary software to StackOverflow](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/support/get-help)

Comment: @Peter O., as Marquizzo said, this is the main support channel for Autodesk Forge API implementation.
What you propose as an alternative for my question?

Comment: Closure vote withdrawn.

Comment: @PabloD. Wait, so you did find a solution after all? If so, you should post it as an official answer to this question so others can benefit from it.

Comment: No, my addendum could be confuse. The solution I found implies set threejs to show edges while loading the geometry. This process can't be done using Forge because it handle the loading process it self. I don't think it would be possible to write my own loader to handle Forge SVF formats.

Comment: Unfortunately no, you cannot write your own SVF loader, and I'm afraid that you cannot (and should not) forcibly re-enable edge rendering. If you have a special use case, consider converting the SVF model to something like glTF using https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils. The glTF you can then load wherever you need, but of course without any performance optimizations provided by Forge Viewer.

Comment: Also, please note that we are not outsourcing the support for Forge Viewer to Stack Overflow. We are using Stack Overflow as the main support channel so that when we answer a question for you, other users have a good chance of finding the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help:

```
viewer.setDisplayEdges(true);
```

Comment: I've tried it, but only works on a desktop browser.
Also tried:

```viewer.impl.setDisplayEdges(true);```

```viewer.impl.edgeColorMain = new Vector4(0,0,0,0.5);```